# Of Yuppies and Yippies and Hippies

Tags: etymology, terminology, history, acronyms, portmanteau-words

While innocently passing by on my way to Big Rep City, I happened to overhear (alright! I was dropping eaves) a dialogue in some podunk Commentary Cafe wherein two fellow ELU consumers were debating whether the term “Yuppie” was an acronym or a portmanteau.

Rapidly approaching the status of ‘ancient of days’, the term Yuppie brought me back (kicking and screaming, mind you) to the Eighties and made me long for the good ol’ days---the Sixties, man---when suddenly I had a flashback and the mental fog that is my cognitive life unaccountably dissipated long enough for me to realize that both of these users were wrong. Yuppie was neither an acronym nor portmanteau, but rather, half ‘n' half.

The Eighties term, Yuppie, was in fact, the illegitimate bastard of the unholy union of the acronym Y.U.P. with the late-Sixties to early Seventies term, YIPPIE, which in turn was an appropriation of the last syllable of the Sixties counter-cultural epithet, HIPPIE. And the previous meaning adhered as an echo in each further elaboration. Just as Yippie was a play on Hippie while adopting an antithetical political stance, so too Yuppie is a play on Yippie, yet conceptually antithetical.

Unfortunately at this point my brain-fog returned and the trail went cold so that’s as far back as I was able to follow the breadcrumbs ... **so 1) does anybody out there know where those crumbs lead? 2) are there any other terms in current usage that have similar developmental histories?**

**Edit**: An integral facet of my OP relates to **the acronym/portmanteau controversy** overheard in commentary and referred to above. This part of my question has only received explicit attention in commentary. My position is clearly stated so, **3) will those of you who feel I err please refute my position, citing to authority, in answer form?**

Comment: portmanteau how, exactly? It's not combining the latter half, it is simply adding an "ee" sound to allow the word to sound like a real word; a Yup wouldn't be an easy word

Comment: For those who missed the eighties, Y.U.P. stood for *young urban professional*.

Comment: I was young, but I seem to remember that HIPPIE and YIPPIE were concurrent developments of the mid 60's. HIP from the Afro slang: modern, sophisticated, and YIP from Abbie Hoffmand's Youth International Party.

Comment: If you look it up, you'll find that Yippie was introduce almost simultaneously, if a trifle later, with *hippie*, in the late '60s.

Comment: No, fellas, sorry, Hippie predates Yippie by about 5 years (I was there, I think) and the term was a play off Hippie and meant to be it's philosophical and political antitheses

Comment: To my recollection "hippie" came first and was someone who was "hip" but not one of those old-guard "beatniks".  "Yippie" followed shortly thereafter, initially tied with a particular political movement (Youth International Party), and developed some other meanings, often derogatory.  Like "yippie", "yuppie" is a portmanteau of an acronym, but "yuppie" has no real common meaning with the other two but is simply borrowing the popular "-pie" suffix.  (I'm thinking there were a bunch of other short-lived "-pie" suffix words in that time frame.)

Comment: @ScotM - "Hip" was a term used by the "Beatniks" since the 50s, at least.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - A portmanteau or portmanteau word, also called a *blend* in linguistics, is a combination of taking parts (but not all) of two (or more) words or their sounds (morphemes) and their meanings into a single new word. from wikipedia

Comment: Yes, @HotLicks, from Afro slang in the 40's and transformed to HIP**PIE** in the 60's :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip_(slang)

Comment: The usual, Liberty caps, cubensis, amanita ... and, uh, some others.

Comment: Young, Upwardly Mobile Professionals *should* have been called **Yumpies**, but the 60's won out.

Comment: Little Eva - the meaning of portmanteau was not the problem. It is just obviously not a portmanteau.

Comment: How so? @RoryAlsop

Comment: You aren't adding an ending from another word. See my earlier comment.

Comment: I think the technical term is [*blend word*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_word), if that's what you're asking :)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read all the comments. I see you also mentioned *blend word*.  I'd say "blend word" fits nicely, yuppie: YUP + Y = IES, the -y suffix is a very common one. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-y

Comment: @Mari-Lou A - The singular form is yuppie *not* yuppy; plural is yuppies. Also Yippie is distinct from the exclamation "yipp**ee**!" :-)

Comment: Yes, but in the 60s a [*hippy*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hippy) (also hippie) was a long-haired free-spirit individual. And the -ie has the same sound as -y

Comment: Two questions which may be of interest to you 1) [Origin of the “-y” or “-ie” diminutive suffix to denote intimacy/tenderness?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/origin-of-the-y-or-ie-diminutive-suffix-to-denote-intimacy-tenderness-e?rq=1) and [How are diminutives formed in recent English words?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7399/how-are-diminutives-formed-in-recent-english-words)

Comment: @HotLicks: the analog is obviously 'puppies'. Kittens just aren't in the same league.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I thought it was *Young Urban Professionals*

Comment: @WS2 - There were several variations on the theme.  I think I heard "Upwardly Mobile" before I heard "Urban".

Comment: I'd say that the ppie is a diminutive and its appearance in other words doesn't qualify as a portmanteau.

Comment: @ScotM: Despite having grown up in times when hippies were commonplace, I don't recall ever seeing or hearing the term 'yippie' applied to a group of people before.

Comment: The monicker yippies was not nearly as viral as hippies: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hippies%2C+yippies&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chippies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyippies%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @ScotM - true, true. Also run this set: "hippy, hippie"

Comment: Yes they were, but the ***current*** usage tends toward totally different meanings with maybe a touch of allusion.

Comment: @ScotM - please explain.

Comment: Examining the books tabulated in the graph: Hippy Potto is a hippo...Home Interaction Programme for Parents and Youngsters...Hippy the dog from the 1940's...I couldn't see enough of hippy end to determine its meaning...**Interestingly**, when it's used to describe the the 60's 70's experience, ***hippy*** seems to be the **adjectival** form: hippy clothes, hippy hat, hippy this, hippy that; while ***hippie*** dominates the **noun** form.

Comment: *Hippy* is **polysemous**, including the acronym of *Home Interaction Programme for Parents and Youngsters* and other meanings along with its "dominant" definition from the 60's. *Hippy* is also **homophonous**, including the affectionate diminutive of *hippopotamus*. Those two issues multiply the ambiguity of every word's semantic field. https://sites.google.com/a/sheffield.ac.uk/all-about-linguistics/branches/semantics/what-is-semantics

Comment: +1 @ScotM - Polysemous: multiple meanings; homophonous: same sounds, distinct meanings, Got it. diminutive hippopotamus: oxymoron. ;-) Thank you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It all starts with a little slang [*hep*:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hep&allowed_in_frame=0)

> "aware, up-to-date," first recorded 1908 in "Saturday Evening Post,"
>   but said to be underworld slang, of unknown origin.
>
> Variously said to have been the name of "a fabulous detective who
>   operated in Cincinnati" [Louis E. Jackson and C.R. Hellyer, "A
>   Vocabulary of Criminal Slang," 1914] or a saloonkeeper in Chicago who
>   "never quite understood what was going on ... (but) thought he did"
>   ["American Speech," XVI, 154/1].
>
> Taken up by jazz musicians by 1915; hepcat "addict of swing music" is
>   from 1938. With the rise of hip (adj.) by the 1950s, the use of hep
>   ironically became a clue that the speaker was unaware and not
>   up-to-date.

*Hep* grew up with his little sister *[hip:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip_(slang))*

> in the sense of "aware, in the know" is first attested in
>   a 1902 cartoon by Tad Dorgan,[8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youth_International_Party) and first appeared in print in a 1904
>   novel by George Vere Hobart, Jim Hickey, A Story of the One-Night
>   Stands, where an African American character uses the slang phrase "Are
>   you hip?".[9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Ties) Early currency of the term (as the past participle
>   hipped, meaning informed), is further documented in the 1914 novel The
>   Auction Block by Rex Beach:
>
> His collection of Napoleana is the finest in this country; he is an
>   authority on French history of that period—in fact, he's as nearly
>   hipped on the subject as a man of his powers can be considered hipped
>   on anything.[10](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=yuppie&searchmode=none)

[etymonline.com:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hip&allowed_in_frame=0)

> "informed," 1904, apparently originally in black slang, probably a
>   variant of hep (1), with which it is identical in sense, though it is
>   recorded four years earlier.

The broader culture tasted [*hip* and *hep*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip_(slang)) in the 40's:

> After the Second World War, the term moved into general parlance, Jack
>   Kerouac for example describing his mid-century contemporaries as "the
>   new American generation known as the 'Hip' (the Knowing)";[11] while
>   in 1947, Harry "The Hipster" Gibson wrote the song "It Ain't Hep"
>   about the switch from hep to hip:
>
> Hey you know there's a lot of talk going around about this hip and hep
>   jive. Lots of people are going around saying "hip." Lots of squares
>   are coming out with "hep." Well the hipster is here to inform you what
>   the jive is all about.

They dumped *hep* and drank *hip* with the [Beatnicks](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beatnik) through the 50's and into the 60's:

> : a young person who was part of a social group in the 1950s and early
>   1960s that rejected the traditional rules of society and encouraged
>   people to express themselves through art

The Beatniks were called *hipsters*, but they were transformed to *[hippies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippie)* when they mainlined their sophisticated, fashionable, up-to-date rejection of the status quo through the 60's and 70's:

> The word '*hippie*' came from *hipster*, and was initially used to
>   describe beatniks who had moved into New York City's Greenwich Village
>   and San Francisco's Haight-Ashbury district. The origins of the terms
>   hip and hep are uncertain, although by the 1940s both had become part
>   of African American jive slang and meant "sophisticated; currently
>   fashionable; fully up-to-date".[1](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hip&allowed_in_frame=0)[3](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hip&allowed_in_frame=0)
>   The Beats adopted the term hip, and early hippies inherited the
>   language and countercultural values of the Beat Generation. Hippies
>   created their own communities, listened to psychedelic music, embraced
>   the sexual revolution, and used drugs such as cannabis, LSD, peyote
>   and psilocybin mushrooms to explore altered states of consciousness.

Abbie Hoffman launched the [**Y**outh **I**nternational **P**arty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youth_International_Party) on December 31, 1967, and they co-opted the conventional contempt in the *hippies* monicker by attaching the same derogatory suffix *-pies* to their acronym *YIPpies*:

> The Yippies had no formal membership or hierarchy. Abbie Hoffman,
>   Anita Hoffman, Jerry Rubin, Nancy Kurshan, and Paul Krassner founded
>   the Yippies (according to his own account, Krassner coined the name)
>   at a meeting in Abbie and Anita's New York flat on December 31,
>   1967.[7](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hip&allowed_in_frame=0) "If the press had created 'hippie,' could not we five hatch the 'yippie'?" Abbie Hoffman wrote.[4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip_(slang))

Eventually, the *Hippies* and *Yippies* made babies with all that free sex, but in the 80's, their children rebelled against the counterculture, as displayed in the wildly popular television sitcom [Family Ties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Ties):

> an American sitcom that aired on NBC from September 22, 1982 until May
>   14, 1989. The series, created by Gary David Goldberg, reflected the
>   move in the United States from the cultural liberalism of the 1960s
>   and 1970s to the conservatism of the 1980s.[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip_(slang)) This was particularly
>   expressed through the relationship between young Republican Alex P.
>   Keaton (Michael J. Fox) and his ex-hippie parents, Steven and Elyse
>   Keaton.

The "adherents" of this conservative backlash were labeled [Yuppies](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=yuppie&searchmode=none) which apparently blended the derogatory suffix *-pies* from *hippies* and *yippies* with the new acronym:

> 1982, acronym from "young urban professional," ousting competition
>   from yumpie (1984), from "young upward-mobile professional," and yap
>   (1984), from "young aspiring professional." The word was felt as an
>   insult by 1985.

The contracted blend of the acronym *YUP* with *hippie* and *yippie* suggests a classification of *portmanteau*. The worthy objection arises that attaching a common -ie suffix with the extra *p* is not actually a blend, but it is my opinion that the shared emotional baggage of these three iconic *-pies* cemented a unique linguistic bond that transcends a shared suffix--they became the nucleus of a new semantic family of cultural affinity.

### So the spaced-out *hippie* *yippies* lived happily ever after with the stressed-out *yuppies* and all their other *-pie* progeny.

---

www.etymonline.com

en.wikipedia.org

www.merriam-webster.com

Comment: +1 Brother, you're blowin' what little mind I got left.

Comment: So Alex P. Keaton---aka Michael J. Fox---was TV's prototypical Yuppie!

Comment: This is a great answer (+1) and very informative but it seems to be missing the actual point of the OP. After all this research is _yuppie_ an acronym, a portmanteau or a combination of the two? Is a suffix enough to make it a portmanteau?

Comment: It is my opinion, that yuppie is the contracted blend of an acronym and hippie/yippie, which classifies it as a portmanteau. Calling it an acronym is a tougher call, but as one who is comfortable drawing outside the lines, I have no problem with Little Eva's designation of "hybrid." I will add my portmanteau designation to the answer presently.

Comment: Thanks for verifying what I thought. I didn't mean to stir up a fire storm :)

Comment: I propose that it should be considered an ***acromanteau*** (not to be confused with an [*acromantula*](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Acromantula).)

Comment: @Hellion - was Shelob also an *acromantula*?

Comment: @LittleEva, in spirit, certainly, if not in name.  :-)

Comment: This use of a common suffix seems somewhat like the way _-gate_ has become a suffix indicating a controversy or scandal. Is there a linguistic term for these types of formulations?

Comment: Very good analogy, @Barmar. A new milieu is attached to an existing morpheme.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, The word "portmanteau" was first used in this context by Lewis Carroll in the book Through the Looking-Glass (1871), in which Humpty Dumpty explains to Alice the coinage of the unusual words in Jabberwocky, where "slithy" means "lithe and slimy" and "mimsy" is "flimsy and miserable." Wikipedia, “portmanteau” [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau)

Comment: Therefore “yippie”, “being an admixture of the words “hippie” & “yippee” (an exclamation expressing wild excitement or delight) is, definitively, a portmanteau; whereas “yuppie”, a blending of the portmanteau “yippie” with the acronym “Y.U.P.” seems to occupy a gray-area and its designation as a portmanteau would rest upon whether or no one feels that the acronym “Y.U.P.” qualifies as a “word.” Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the historical threads that ScotM identifies in his excellent answer, several other *-pies* formations that were current in the 1960s and 1970s may have contributed to the adoption of *yuppies* as shorthand for members of the sociological category "young urban professionals." To wit: *preppies*, *bippies*, *blippies*, *dippies*, and *trippies*.

The term *preppies* goes back to at least 1963, when it appeared in the [*Harvard Alumni Bulletin*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-LflAAAAMAAJ&q=%22preppies%22&dq=%22preppies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4ZnjVKrZAY7xoATUioFw&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAjgU), volume 66 [combined snippets]:

> Despite University efforts to the contrary, House stereotypes continue to play a dominant role in the freshman's choice. Winthrop, he has heard, is for athletes; Eliot is filled with **preppies** and clubbies; Adams is literary or "beat"; Kirkland, "musical" and friendly; Quincy, political; Dunster, "gung-ho"; and so on: ...

A 1963 issue of [*The New Yorker*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BhcnAQAAIAAJ&q=%22preppies%22&dq=%22preppies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EpvjVIjvKsG5oQSUnICYDg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBzgo) reported that there was a "foolish, harmless musical spoof" called *Preppies* at The Promenade on Broadway at 76th Street that year.

Although most people of a certain age remember *bippies* as a euphemism for anatomical posteriors, popularized in 1967 by the cast of the TV show *Rowan & Martin's Laugh-In*, it was also a slang term,as explained in U.S. Senate Committee on the Judiciary, [*Methaqualone (Quaalude, Sopor) Traffic, Abuse and Regulation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MgTTZzKTmcIC&q=%22designated+by+Women%27s+Wear+Daily%29,+but%22&dq=%22designated+by+Women%27s+Wear+Daily%29,+but%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G57jVN6UDtGqyATJyoHwCA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA) (1973):

> San Francisco society chronicler Meria Zellerbach says she has heard of no run on dermatologists for silicone among that city's **bippies** (a term not so long ago in vogue for BPs, or Beautiful People, so designated by *Women's Wear Daily*), but of course plastic surgery to shore up sags and tighten against the stresses of age continues to be popular.

Another early reference to bippies suggests the jocular element in the usage. From [*Congressional Record*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JmVtZrA0kC8C&q=%22bippies%22&dq=%22bippies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tKLjVIKvI9LVoASlzYBo&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBg) (1969) [combined snippets]:

> This wave of discontent, with all its ominous implications, doesn't come from **the hippies, the bippies or the dippies**. It doesn't come from the Far Left, the Far Right or the Far Anything.
>
> It comes from citizens—your neighbors—— the men and women who have tried to fulfill their lives in honorable careers with the postal service.

And from [*Dairy and Ice Cream Field*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sxkJAQAAMAAJ&q=%22bippies%22&dq=%22bippies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tKLjVIKvI9LVoASlzYBo&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ) (1969) [combined snippets]:

> Whether they're called Hippies, **Bippies**, Boy Scouts or Flower Children, teen-agers in the United States are spending money like mad.

The heyday of *blippies* is more of a blip. The term shows up in Reginald Major, [*A Panther Is a Black Cat*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tc0WAQAAIAAJ&q=%22black+hippies%22&dq=%22black+hippies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yKDjVLCtLtGwogTMlIHABw&ved=0CC0Q6AEwBDgK) (1971) [combined snippets]:

> Reportedly the SNCC [Student Nonviolent Coordinating Committee] staff was wary of the Panthers. They did not accept the Panther ten-point program, and also rejected the idea of conducting  black people's plebiscite. The plebiscite was a program thought up by Eldridge Cleaver, and SNCC might have rejected it on that basis. Cleaver had not exactly endeared himself to SNCC when he described them as being primarily composed of "**blippies**," black hippies.

The word *dippies* shows up in the duplicative term *hippie-dippies* and also as a (rather ill-defined) term on its own, essentially meaning "crazy people." From Henry Williamson, [*The Golden Virgin*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3okIAQAAIAAJ&q=%22dippies%22&dq=%22dippies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fqPjVKBCw96gBK_wgIgD&ved=0CCEQ6AEwATgK) (1957) [combined snippets]:

> You see, midear," he went on, in a different voice, as he pulled out the ends of his moustache with finger and thumb, "if you tell the jolly old doc. he may get me sent away among the genuine **dippies**, and I'm not really that, you know. You see what happens is this. I can't control my thoughts of what happened when that mine went up taking me for a joy ride. ..."

On the other hand, *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) traces *dippy* as an adjective to 1899 (with "origin unknown") and says that it means "foolish." The word probably retained that sense as well as "a crazy person" when used as a noun later in the twentieth century.

The term *trippies* arose in connection with 1960s drug culture. From [*Liberation: An Independent Monthly*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hq45AQAAIAAJ&q=%22trippies%22&dq=%22trippies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-6XjVICGNYOxogTby4KgCg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1966) [combined snippets]:

> Hippie reject the System, and attempt to drop out from it in various ways, but many do not try to do so through drugs. It is important to distinguish between dropouts for whom drugs are the closest thing to an organizing life principle, and dropouts for whom sex or poetry or "community" or something else comes closest to an organizing life principle. I will here call the drug-centered people "**trippies**."
>
> Hippies and **trippies** share a common point of departure—and I share it with them.

And from [*Tradition*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wnZTAAAAYAAJ&q=%22drug%27s+religious+implications.+From+our%22&dq=%22drug%27s+religious+implications.+From+our%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6KfjVJOEBYLtoATH34LYBw&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ), volume 10 (1969) [combined snippets]:

> ***Religious Experiences*** Not a few "**trippies**" have reported on the similarity of their experiences to the reports of religious mystics and quite a few papers have discussed the drug's religious implications.

Given the evident predilection in U.S. English for *-pies* forms, it is hardly surprising that *Y.U.P.s* should in short order become known as *yuppies*. They were followed in short order by [*buppies*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BMLH7cJzX5MC&pg=PA207&dq=%22buppies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yavjVJvSA870oAS12oCQBw&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22buppies%22&f=false) ("black urban professionals"), [*muppies*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gOK2gn2KGSUC&q=%22muppies%22&dq=%22muppies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oKvjVK-FFs7ZoATq5YKADw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg) ("Mennonite urban professionals), and (more recently) [*bappies*](https://books.google.com/books?id=g00sAQAAMAAJ&q=%22bappies%22&dq=%22bappies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=g6rjVP6nPMXqoASguYKQAQ&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBjgK) ("booming aspirational and previously poor").

Comment: That's great. I finally know what Rowan & Martin meant by, "You bet your sweet bippie!" Anatomical posteriors!

Comment: I vaguely recall "dippie" being sometimes used as a term for "druggie".  Or at least that's the way I interpreted it from the context.  But for awhile there you had "pie" coming at you from all directions -- like Soupy Sales was on the set.

Comment: Absolutely impressive work. I know magicians don't reveal their secrets but I gotta ask, Sven, How do ya do it? How do ya dig this stuff up? And chime in on the acronym/portmanteau/hybrid controversy. +1, only wish I could award you and Scot more.

Comment: Yeah, that's right @Hot Licks, I was thinking of "pies" myself. Do you recall the "Pie Brigade" or the "Pie-man"? They were actually a counter-culture co-op or commune and they'd go around 'pying'(?) celebs and politicians with cream pies! They were a riot.

Comment: Very vaguely remember "Pie-man".  But I was nowhere near counter-culture at the time (not for want of trying, mind you, but the only "counter-culture" in my backwater was the crew at the soda bar in the drug store).

Comment: @LittleEva: Ngram is a great tool for locating examples of words, but it is highly volatile—meaning that a search for a word or phrase over the years 1800–2000 may not turn up an occurrence that a search for the same term or phrase over the years 1800–1875 does. Partly that happens because the Ngram machine is trippy (or dippy); but partly it happens because the search engine applies some sort of hierarchy of value to the search results it finds, and when there are a lot of results, it drops out lower-value matches from magazines, etc. But those may be the ones you want...

Comment: Right, Sven. Ngram might have even been coded by an old Bay Area hippie, which would explain the "dippy" functionality ... the sins of the father and all ... Did you run a Ngram query on these terms? Will Ngram isolate specific occurrences of the search terms?

Comment: So, in other words you get more specificity by breaking the search parameters down to smaller sets?

Comment: The place to look for specific results is in the "Search in Google Books" entries beneath the Ngram line graph. For your question, I eventually searched for the terms _yippies_, _preppies_, _bippies_, _buppies_, _yuppies_, _dippies_, _trippies_, and _chappies_ (which turned out to be a UK term far more than a US one), for the time period 1950–1990. The more-specific date sets approach works well to a certain point, but if you get too granular the search flips out and gives you nothing. So you have to fiddle with the parameters to see what works in a particular case.

Comment: Ngram shows Google Books search results only in the "graph" version of an Ngram. To convert the one in your comment into a graph version of the same, sub in _graph_ for _interactive_chart_ in the URL: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hippy%2C+hippie&year_start=1966&year_end=1975&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chippy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chippie%3B%2Cc0%22. You can create your own Ngram graph at https://books.google.com/ngrams. To convert a graph into a chart displayable on EL&U, just sub out _graph_ in the URL in favor of _chart_, and then use ![](URL GOES HERE)

Comment: Of all the pies in the 1960's!

Comment: **@ScotM - you bet your sweet bippie!**

Comment: What, no _commies_?

Comment: @Codeswitcher - just now caught-up to your comment, **+1**, good point. How'd we miss that one!?

Comment: One member of the _-pie_ group that I neglected to investigate is _chippie_, a term frequently used in the mid-20th century to identify a promiscuous woman who was not a prostitute. Reference books report that it was still in use in the 1960s and beyond, though I have never heard anyone use it in everyday speech.