# What is the correct spelling for "Hippie-Dippy Bologna"?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, phrase-usage

Because while that is technically the correct spelling for each word, but as a phrase it doesn't seem to work well together.  It lacks symmetry (Hipp**ie** vs. Dipp**y**) and uses the extremely rare-yet-proper Italian "bologna".

Origin:  The phrase is used with delightful comic effect in [*The Lego Movie*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/) and quoted on [wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Lego_Movie#Lord_Business) as "hippie, dippy baloney".

Consider:

- "Hippie-dippie" for symmetry?  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hippie-dippie) supports it.  (Wiktionary includes it as [a short entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hippie-dippie)).
- Hippy?  Would match "Dippy".  Although "Hippie" has the most support in usage and prescription (on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hippie) and [English stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227992/of-yuppies-and-yippies-and-hippies))

  - And yet [Google suggests](http://google.com/search?q=hippie+dippy+baloney+lego) "**Hippy** Dippy Baloney Lego" for a "**Hippie** Dippy Baloney Lego" search, as if "Hippie" were misspelled based on the comparative number of search results.
- Dippie?  Would match "Hippie".

  - And yet scarce presence [among Internet dictionaries](http://google.com/search?q=dippie+in+a+dictionary).
  - Whereas [Dippy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dippy)
- Baloney?  Far more common in usage and [growing in dictionary acceptance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/baloney).
- Dash between hippie and dippy?  Dash between all three?

The question is: How best to spell "Hippie-Dippie Baloney"?

Comment: Spell it however you like. Plenty of people use the spelling [***hippy***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+was+a+hippy%22), and even more use [***boloney***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all+boloney%22) rather than *baloney* (or your supposedly "correct" *bologna*).

Comment: *Hippie-dippie* has been around longer than The Lego Movie. There must be some kind of conventional spelling for it, I should think. Also, seems like it is a compound word rather than something one might think of spelling separately, like a whatdoyoucallit phrasal repeat like "thingy-dingy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case for Hippy Dippy Balony: the spelling of *hippy* with a final *y* predates the spelling ending *ie*:

> One of the earliest attestations of the term ***hippy*** is found in the
>   "Dictionary of Hip Words and Phrases" included in the liner notes for
>   the 1959 comedy album *How to Speak Hip*, a parody based on the
>   burgeoning Greenwich Village scene.
>   (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology_of_hippie)

Further it is clearly an adjective.  *Hippy* is also a valid adjective in every dictionary I checked, meaning "having big hips." Further, the word *hippy* in the phrase is clearly an adjective.

"Balony" is the best way to spell baloney/bologna because to spell it correctly would be like spelling out "OK" as "okae".

Comment: Plus "Hipp**y**" is pleasantly similar to "Gyps**y**".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_the_Romani_people#Gypsy_and_Gipsy

Comment: Alas, I cannot mark this answer as **_the_** answer because of its treatment of "balony"/baloney/bologna.
Compare [baloney](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/baloney) to [balony](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/balony).  (How strange that [boloney](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boloney) is fine but not balony/bolony.)

Answer (score 1):

On the Warner Home Video DVD release, the English subtitles render it

> hippie-dippie baloney

(But, perhaps the subtitles do not represent the intended or scripted spelling.)