# Is there a British slang word for "company man"?

Tags: british-english

I remember coming across a word that was British, and seemed to be a more specific reference to what we call a "company man" in the US. But this was a while ago and I forget it.

Comment: Is your answer here: [Derogatory term for a corporate employee](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227761/derogatory-term-for-a-corporate-employee)

Comment: Though a Yank myself, I have to ask: how exactly might you describe the sort of person that "we" call a "company man" in the US?

Comment: You mean like a "yes man" or a sycophant?

Comment: I'd suggest "corporate man", but without more information there's not much point posting a wild guess which may be nothing like what you're looking for. More context please @JayZee!

Comment: Could you be thinking of [Jobsworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jobsworth)? Not really a 'company man', but definitely distinctly British.

Comment: Jobsworth it is! Wow, I was way off, time must have really warped what I remembered of that term. Thanks! Is there a way to mark a comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jobsworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jobsworth) - (from Wikipedia)

> "Jobsworth" is a British colloquial word derived from the phrase "I
>   can't do that, it's more than my job's worth", meaning taking the
>   initiative and performing an action that is beyond what the person
>   feels is in their job description. The Oxford English Dictionary
>   defines it as "A person in authority (esp. a minor official) who
>   insists on adhering to rules and regulations or bureaucratic
>   procedures even at the expense of common sense."[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jobsworth) Jonathon Green
>   similarly defines "jobsworth" as "a minor factotum whose only status
>   comes from enforcing otherwise petty regulations".